# should I use .rank or .order_id?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

accessing `order_id` property of a `ScoredDocument` object in `SearchResults` object generates following error in log:

`DeprecationWarning: order_id is deprecated; use rank instead
  logging.debug(document.order_id)`

However documentation here refers to `order_id`: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/scoreddocumentclass

Which is correct? I am using SDK 1.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `rank`. I've filed a bug to fix that documentation. (I work on the Search API)

Answer (score 4):

Documentation updates slower then the code, you should flow whatever the latest code recommends you to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the [SdkReleaseNotes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) of the version 1.6.6 - May22, 2012 it writes:

"The Search API has deprecated the `order_id` attribute on Document class. It has been replaced with the `rank` attribute."

So obviously you should use `rank`.